# My stereo lost power

Tags: audio, mustang

Hey so I recently messed with my headlights on my Mustang 2002 but in the process I guess I lost power to my stereo? What happened and how do I fix this ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a blown fuse.  The interior fuse panel on the 2002 Mustang is under the dash on the drivers side, to the left of the steering column.

[image: Thanks http://diagrams.hissind.com/2002-ford-mustang-fuse-panel-under-dash-diagram/]

Number 27 in the diagram is your best bet.